# Transit visa for Finland while final destination is Italy

Tags: transit, finland

I have issued an Italian short-term visa to attend a course. My connecting flight is from Finland. Do I have to get a transit visa for the layover in Finland?

Comment: @Khan it's always important to include your citizenship in this kind of question

Answer (score 0):

Both Italy and Finland are in the Schengen Area. You will pass border control in Finland where border agent will stamp your Schengen visa (check if visa is valid for all Schengen area) and the Finland-Italy flight will be like a domestic flight.